# The product of three consecutive numbers equals the product of two other consecutive numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, multivariable-calculus, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Is there a systematic way to find positive integer solutions satisfying:

$f(x,y) = x^{3} - y^{2} - x - y$?

Interestingly, wolfram alpha lists about six pairs of integer solutions, but those solutions did not include an obvious solution: $x = 6$ and $y = 14$.

What is interesting about the pair $(x, y) = (6, 14)$ is that it allows us to write: $5\times 6 \times 7 = 14 \times 15$. One wonders if there are other numbers where the result of the multiplication of three consecutive numbers equals to the product of two other consecutive numbers.

Comment: Well $1\times 2\times 3=2\times 3$ is a cheap example.

Comment: There will be infinite number of those if we were to go that route:-)

Comment: How so?   There are, of course, even cheaper examples if you allow $0$, but I am assuming that you don't.   For the full list, it's a question of the integer points on the elliptic curve $x^3-x=y^2+y$.

Comment: If one considers multiplication by units, then the problem would not be interesting.

Comment: I did say that solution was cheap, but I don't see infinitely many solutions, even cheap ones.  Note:  when I asked WA about the elliptic curve it did in fact return your solution (as well as the cheap ones and some negative versions of your solution).  I think it knows the standard methods for find integer points on such curves, but I would not swear to that.

Comment: I think it can be written in the form of $Y^2=aX^3+bX+c$ for suitable $X, Y$. Then the theory of elliptic curves can be utilized to find the solutions.

Comment: That is correct: $(y + \frac{1}{2})^{2} = x^{3} - x + \frac{1}{4}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sage, to get the integral points on your elliptic curve:

```
R.<x,y> = QQ[]
E = EllipticCurve(x^3-y^2-x-y)
E.integral_points(both_signs=true)
```

It returns:

```
[(-1 : -1 : 1),
 (-1 : 0 : 1),
 (0 : -1 : 1),
 (0 : 0 : 1),
 (1 : -1 : 1),
 (1 : 0 : 1),
 (2 : -3 : 1),
 (2 : 2 : 1),
 (6 : -15 : 1),
 (6 : 14 : 1)]
```

So the positive integer solutions are $x=2,y=2$ and $x=6,y=14$.

Answer (score 0):

First, it's no surprise that the solutions allow you to write the product of three consecutive numbers equal to the product of two other consecutive numbers.

Consider your pair $(x,y)$

The product of three consecutive integers is given by $(x-1)x(x+1)=x^3-x$

The product of two consecutive integers is given by $y(y+1)=y^2+y$

If these are equal, then $x^3-x=y^2+y$, which is the same as $x^3-x-y^2-y=0$

Comment: That is the way I derived the problem. My question is really whether the pair I had noted was the only positive non-unit pair satisfying the given function. I was looking for any technique already known for showing that that is the case.